# A method for limiting the number of results the Get Feature Interaction brings through in OpenLayers 3

Tags: javascript, openlayers, openlayers-2

I have so far managed to return a list of all the customer names at a single point when the vector layer is clicked on. I am looking to limit this to only show the first (or just one) record.Could this be achieved through a modification of the following?

```
   function projectClient(browserEvent) {
    var coordinate = browserEvent.coordinate;
    var pixel = map.getPixelFromCoordinate(coordinate);
    var el = document.getElementById('projectClient');
    el.innerHTML = '';
    map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(pixel, function(feature) {
      el.innerHTML += feature.get('Proj_Client') + '<br>';
    });
  }
  map.on('pointerdown', projectClient);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the API docs (http://openlayers.org/en/v3.4.0/apidoc/ol.Map.html?unstable=true#forEachFeatureAtPixel):  To stop detection, callback functions can return a truthy value.

```
map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(pixel, function(feature) {
  el.innerHTML += feature.get('Proj_Client') + '<br>';
  return true;
});
```